# $.each() not properly iterating over array

Tags: jquery, iteration, associative-array

I am having an issue iterating over an associative array with jQuery. I have four spans in the html page... and I use json to form an array of the text() values from those to build an array of dimensions

```
var export_pkg = { 
           height : $('#cubeiq_hght').text(),
           length : $('#cubeiq_lnth').text(), 
            depth : $('#cubeiq_wdth').text(), 
           weight : $('#cubeiq_wght').text() 
};

$.each(export_pkg, function(key,value){

    alert(key + ' ' + value);

});
```

For a reason  I cannot figure out... the length of export_pkg is always the text value for length within the array. Both Firefox and IE's developer tools shows export_pkg to be an array with 4 items and it has the correct value. But when I get to the $.each block... it ignores the object and just uses the second entry as the length of the object.

Example: If the array had a {length: 10} the alert box appears 10 times no matter what the value of the others is. I cannot figure out for the life of me why it does not run 4 times as I would expect it to.

Here is a jslint link http://jsfiddle.net/fFDfU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your object has the property `length` which `$.each` uses to iterate over the array. Since you are defining it, you are screwing up the behavior of the method.  Try changing the name to something else like `_length`

```
var export_pkg = { height : '10', _length : '3', depth : '30',  weight : '40' };
```

Comment: AHHHHH that makes total sense now! I'm overwriting one of the built in properties! Thank you so very much!

Comment: @DirtyBirdNJ: Nice, but just what I said 3 minutes before and with a working Fiddle to you...

Answer (score 7):

First, you isn't using an *array*, it's an *object*. But you can iterate object properties using `each` as you want.

The `length` property is used by `each` to see how many items need to be iterated. Since you have a `length` inside your object, it confuses `each`.

I suggest you to change that property name: http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/fFDfU/1/

Comment: Yep, nail on the head sir... I was overwriting a built in property. Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 5):

What you have is not an array of objects but an object with properties. An array is defined like this:

```
var array = [ 
{ 
    height : $('#cubeiq_hght').text(),
    length : $('#cubeiq_lnth').text(), 
    depth : $('#cubeiq_wdth').text(), 
    weight : $('#cubeiq_wght').text() 
}, 
{
    height : $('#cubeiq_hght').text(),
    length : $('#cubeiq_lnth').text(), 
    depth : $('#cubeiq_wdth').text(), 
    weight : $('#cubeiq_wght').text() 
}, 
{
    ...
}
];
```

then you can loop:

```
$.each(array, function() {
    alert(this.height + ' ' + this.length + ...);
});
```

And to achieve what you want to achieve (loop through the properties of an object) you could do this:

```
for (var propertyName in export_pkg) {
   alert(propertyName + ' ' + export_pkg[propertyName]);   
}
```

Comment: The `each` can be used to loop object properties, like the OP wants.